# Theme customizer not working

Tags: theme-customizer

I am trying to add theme support for custom background using the following code in functions.php file:

```
function supp_custom_bg() {
    $defaults = array(
        'default-color'          => '',
        'default-image'          => '',
        'wp-head-callback'       => '_custom_background_cb',
        'admin-head-callback'    => '',
        'admin-preview-callback' => ''
    );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'supp_custom_bg', 20 );
```

and the options now are activated in the customizer but no effect on the theme.

Note: The `wp_head` is added to the `<head>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to use this feature:

1. Add `add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );` to `functions.php`
2. Use `body_class()` in your `body` tag like this:  `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`
3. use `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in your `head` tag

if you go to the customizer should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much i was missing the `<?php body_class(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to customize how background image is implemented in your theme then do share the code of your `_custom_background_cb` callback function. If not and simply wanted to add background image then remove `wp-head-callback`.

Comment: Actually I tried only the default-color argument but also no response

Comment: Is your `_custom_background_cb` code print the color or background image in CSS in your head?

Comment: Nothing is printed.. actually I didn't define this function but after the first try using the default-color I copied these lines from codex to check but nothing also changed

Comment: Could you please answer with right way to use this feature with full code and I will try to figuer out what was wrong with me

Comment: I see. if that is the case then you only need `add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );` and it should work -:

Comment: Sorry no changes